# How to solve this first-order nonlinear ordinary differential equation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> Obtain the solution to the DE $$\dfrac{dy}{dx} = \dfrac{1+y^2}{1+x^2}$$
>   (A) $\dfrac{Cx}{1-Cx}$
>
> (B) $\dfrac{Cx}{1+Cx}$
>
> (C) $\dfrac{C-x}{1-Cx}$
>
> (D) $\dfrac{1-Cx}{x+C}$
>
> (E) $\dfrac{x+C}{1-Cx}$

I can solve this ODE by separation, but I get an answer with a tangent, $y=\tan( \arctan(x) + C)$

How can I either rewrite this to the acceptable form or solve this ODE differently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:**

$$\tan (u+v)=\frac{\tan u + \tan v}{1 - \tan u \tan v}$$